# How to chain multiple T-SQL statements (separated by GO's) into a single call to SQL using SqlCommand

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sqlcommand

I have a C# desktop app that calls various SQL Server stored procedures to perform various work of exporting and importing data to a SQL Server 2008 R2 database.

These all work fine, no problem. And my app calls them just fine with all parameters etc.

In order to "assist the user", I'm coding a button to add all the stored procedures to the configured database.  To this end, I've created a script along the lines of:

```
USE [%DATABASENAME%]
GO        

IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[spMyProc1]') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[spMyProc1]
GO

IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[spMyProc2]') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[spMyProc2]
GO

IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[spMyProc3]') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[spMyProc3]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spMyProc1]
        @VariousParams varchar(100),
    @ResultText varchar(4000) OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
  -- Code removed for brevity
END

GO
--

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spMyProc2]
        @VariousParams varchar(100),
    @ResultText varchar(4000) OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
  -- Code removed for brevity
END

GO
--

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spMyProc3]
        @VariousParams varchar(100),
    @ResultText varchar(4000) OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
  -- Code removed for brevity
END

GO
```

When I run this in SQL Server Management Studio, it runs fine, no problems at all.

However in my C# app, an exception is thrown and I get a boat load of errors as follows:

> Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.
>   Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.
>   Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.
>   Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.
>   Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.
>   Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.
>   'CREATE/ALTER PROCEDURE' must be the first statement in a query batch.
>   A RETURN statement with a return value cannot be used in this context.
>   A RETURN statement with a return value cannot be used in this context.
>   Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@MessageText".
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@ListOfIDsToImport".
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@SourceDataFolder".
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@SourceDataFolder".
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@SequenceNo".
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@UserID".
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@SequenceNo".
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@UserID".
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@ListOfIDsToImport".
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@ListOfIDsToImport".
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@ListOfIDsToImport".
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@MessageText".
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@MessageText".
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@MessageText".
>   Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.
>   The variable name '@PS_DEFAULT' has already been declared. Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure.
>   The variable name '@PS_ERROR_MSG' has already been declared. Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure.
>   The variable name '@PS_ERROR_SEVERITY' has already been declared. Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure.
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@SequenceNo".
>   Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.

(This is what's in the ex.Message as caught by the catch block in the code below).

My code is very straightforward as follows:

```
    bool retVal = false;
    string command = Properties.Resources.MyApp_StoredProcedures.ToString().Replace("%DATABASENAME%", Properties.Settings.Default.DBName);

    try
    {
        sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(command, csSQLConnection._conn);
        sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        retVal = true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        retVal = false;
    }
    finally
    {
        sqlCmd.Dispose();
    }
```

(The replace above simply replaces the placeholder in the USE line at the top of the script and it works as I can see when I step through and over that line).

So basically, what am I doing wrong as the SQL itself seems fine?

Many thanks

Comment: You basically need to break up your script at every `GO` and execute each "sub-script" as a separate call to `SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()`, in order to satisfy requirements like *'CREATE/ALTER PROCEDURE' must be the first statement in a query batch.*

Answer (score 2):

This should be easy...

get rid of GO, that's SSMS specific syntax, the SQL language doesn't require or support it, rather you should terminate your individual create scripts with ; .  Let me know how that goes.

Comment: Thanks - that's removed all the errors relating to the GO statements, however all others remain.  Any other ideas?  The SQL is good, I know it is, as SSMS processes it all fine.

Comment: That won't work - since things like *CREATE/ALTER PROCEDURE' must be the first statement in a query batch.* aren't going to be fixed with this *drop all `GO`* approach ....

Comment: I write my sp's as... CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spMyProc1]
        (@VariousParams varchar(100),
    @ResultText varchar(4000) OUTPUT) notice the ().  Try that and see if it resolves it.

Answer (score 2):

You CANNOT set a single ADO.NET object to execute a script that contains batch terminators("GO") as far as I know.  You would have to do one of two things:

1. Create a SQL Management Studio Object and run it in the background.  I know SQL Management Studio's folder has DLL's that can do work from SSMS.  I have created .NET code to open SSMS for someone and be about to load it, but not execute it directly.
2. Do a for each method and break apart your SQL script to create an array of objects from the 'GO' statements into memory in a List or similar.  Then iterate through that list with a 'foreach' statement to execute each one with the appropriate try/catch blocks.

Answer (score 0):

If the script comes from a [`Stream`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (such as from an embedded resource via [`Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5kx66y1a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), from a [`FileStream`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), or a [`MemoryStream`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).  You can use the following to split the [SSMS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174173.aspx) [SQLCMD](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174187.aspx#Anchor_4) batch scripts that can include `GO`:

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetScriptParts(Stream script)
{
    const string reBatchSeparator = @"^(/\*.\*/)?\s*GO\s*(/\*.*\*/)?\s*(--.*)?$";

    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(script))
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while(!sr.EndOfStream)
        {
            string line = sr.ReadLine();
            if (!batchSeparator.IsMatch(line))
            {
                sb.AppendLine(line);
            }
            else
            {
                string part = sb.ToString();
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(part))
                {
                    yield return part;
                }
                sb.Clear();
            }
        }

        string part = sb.ToString();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(part))
        {
            yield return part;
        }
    }
}
```

The method `ExecuteBatch` sequentially executes the script parts via [`SqlCommand`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
public void ExecuteBatch(SqlConnection conn, Stream script)
{
    foreach (string part in GetScriptParts(script))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();

        cmd.CommandText = part;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```